# Помогите с выводом всплывающего окна после успешной отправки формы

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, form

Нужно сделать так чтобы после успешной отправки формы всплывало окно с сообщение об успешной отправке.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-act").submit(function() {
    var formID = $(this).attr('id');
    var formNm = $('#' + formID);
    var message = $(formNm).find(".popup-basket");
    var formTitle = $(formNm).find(".popup-basket");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'ssets/phpsend-message-to-telegram.php',
      data: formNm.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $('.popup-basket').toggleClass('show');
        message.html(data);
        // formTitle.css("display","block");
        setTimeout(function() {
          formTitle.css("display", "block");
          message.html('');
          $('input').not(':input[type=submit], :input[type=hidden]').val('');
        }, 3000);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, text, error) {
        message.html(error);
        formTitle.css("display", "block");
        setTimeout(function() {
          formTitle.css("display", "block");

          message.html('');
          $('input').not(':input[type=submit], :input[type=hidden]').val('');
        }, 3000);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```
<div class="popup-basket" id="total-basket">
  <div class="popup__overlay">
    <div class="popup__body">
      <a href="" class="popup__close">
        <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
      </a>
      <h3>
        Złóż zamówienie
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="order-form clearfix">
  <form id="form-contact" method="POST" class="form-act" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="prodtitle" class="prod-title" readonly="readonly" tabindex="0" value="test">
    <input type="text" name="name" tabindex="0" placeholder="Imie" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="priceprod" readonly="readonly" tabindex="0" value="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="timeorder" readonly="readonly" tabindex="0" value="test">
    <input name="theme" type="hidden" class="form-input__theme" readonly="readonly" value="test">
    <input type="tel" name="phone" tabindex="0" placeholder="Telefon" required>
    <div class="order-btn">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" type="button">
            Check
        </button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <button type="button" id="pickup">
              Check
          </button>
          <button type="button" id="drop-btn">
              Check-2
          </button>
          <p class="form-message"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="delivery-address">
      <input name="delivery" type="text" tabindex="0" placeholder="Adres dostawy">
    </div>
    <div class="order-send text-center">
      <button type="submit">
          Send
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: А в чём вы видите проблему? Код на первый взгляд правильный.

Comment: Не работает вывод об успешной/не успешной отправке